# Can PostgreSQL index calculations be multithreaded?

Tags: postgresql, index

During a single query write of approximately 300,000 rows with 30 columns all indexed, I noticed that only one core was maxed at a time.

Is there any way to calculate indexes multithreaded for single inserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to calculate indexes multithreaded for single inserts?

Unfortunately, no.

PostgreSQL backends are single-threaded, and a single connection can use only one backend.

There's work to enhance this, but it's a seriously difficult and big job because of PostgreSQL's process-based architecture.

The only real option is to split the insert its self into multiple concurrent connections, each doing part of the work.

Comment: Thank you Craig Ringer!  About your last statement, does that mean that Postgres only partially alters the index on each write?

Comment: @Gracchus the index is incrementally updated, yes. If possible drop it before & recreate it after a big bulk load if you don't mind the impact on concurrent readers.

Comment: In many cases, I have been able to greatly speed up tasks by splitting one insertion query into 32 that run concurrently on a 32 core machine. Postgres 9.6 has added some minimal support for parallelized queries, but I still unfortunately have to do most of mine manually (assisted with Python scripts). I hope Postgres improves in this area since even a single machine is becoming increasingly "horizontal" nowadays.